# How to create a time varying plot (animation) of a 2D array that changes it's values in discrete time steps?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, animation, multidimensional-array

I have the following code where A is a 2D array that represents a plane grid in space. The values it contains are the values of a field that change with time. I want to show this variation in time as an animation.

```
A = np.zeroes((100,100))
for time in range(1000):
    int i,j;
        A[i][j] = A[i][j] + A[i+1][j+1];
```

How can I plot the field values in the array A? Some kind of color coding to represent various ranges of field values perhaps?

Comment: http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/  hope this helps.

Comment: `int i,j; A[i][j] = A[i][j] + A[i+1][j+1];` ain't Python. You probably meant something like `A[:-1, :-1] += A[1:, 1:]` (but check boundary behaviour).